# How to Set a timer on button click in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I am setting a timer on button click

```
$(document).on("click", "[button]", function() {
        var button = document.getElementById('my_btn');
            var time = 5;
            var timer = setInterval(function() {
              if (time > 0) {
                time--;
                button.disabled = true;
                button.innerHTML = 'Please wait for '+time+ ' seconds' ;
                console.log(time);
              }
              if (time === 0) {
                button.disabled = false;
                button.innerHTML = 'Press Me' ;
              }
            }, 1000);
        });
```

this only runs once. When the timer is finished. Then, again when I click on the button. It doesn't show anything and nothing happens.

Comment: You need to reset the `time` variable.

Comment: Time variable has been never assigned a value.

Answer (score 2):

clear your interval in if (time === 0) {

```
if (time === 0) {
  button.disabled = false;
  button.innerHTML = 'Press Me' ;
  clearInterval(timer); // here
}
```